# Unity TcpClient messages sticks together

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tcpclient

I develop some multiplayer game. And use `TcpClient` for it. 
I have this code for Client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;

public class TCPClient : MonoBehaviour {    
    #region private members     
    private TcpClient socketConnection;     
    private Thread clientReceiveThread;     

    private long timestamp;
    #endregion      
    // Use this for initialization  
    void Start () {
        ConnectToTcpServer();     
    }       
    /// <summary>   
    /// Setup socket connection.    
    /// </summary>  
    private void ConnectToTcpServer () {        
        try {           
            clientReceiveThread = new Thread (new ThreadStart(ListenForData));          
            clientReceiveThread.IsBackground = true;            
            clientReceiveThread.Start();        
        }       
        catch (Exception e) {           
            Debug.Log("On client connect exception " + e);      
        }   
    }   
    /// <summary>   
    /// Runs in background clientReceiveThread; Listens for incomming data.     
    /// </summary>     
    private void ListenForData() {      
        try {           
            socketConnection = new TcpClient(MainController.instance.connectIp.text, 8052);             
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];             
            while (true) {              
                // Get a stream object for reading              
                using (NetworkStream stream = socketConnection.GetStream()) {                   
                    int length;                     
                    // Read incomming stream into byte arrary.                  
                    while ((length = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0) {                       
                        var incommingData = new byte[length];                       
                        Array.Copy(bytes, 0, incommingData, 0, length);                         
                        // Convert byte array to string message.                        
                        string serverMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(incommingData);                         
                        Debug.Log("server message received as: " + serverMessage);                  
                        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                        {
                            string[] position = serverMessage.Split(';');
                            MainController.instance.SetBallPosition(float.Parse(position[0]), float.Parse(position[1]));
                        }); 
                    }               
                }           
            }         
        }         
        catch (SocketException socketException) {             
            Debug.Log("Socket exception: " + socketException);         
        }     
    }   

    public IEnumerator ThisWillBeExecutedOnTheMainThread(string message) {

        yield return null;
    }
    /// <summary>   
    /// Send message to server using socket connection.     
    /// </summary>  
    public void SendData(string message) {         
        if (socketConnection == null) {             
            return;         
        }       
        try {           
            // Get a stream object for writing.             
            NetworkStream stream = socketConnection.GetStream();            
            if (stream.CanWrite) {                  
                // Convert string message to byte array.                 
                byte[] clientMessageAsByteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);                 
                // Write byte array to socketConnection stream.                 
                stream.Write(clientMessageAsByteArray, 0, clientMessageAsByteArray.Length);                 
                Debug.Log("Client sent his message - should be received by server");             
            }         
        }       
        catch (SocketException socketException) {             
            Debug.Log("Socket exception: " + socketException);         
        }     
    } 
}
```

And for Server:

```
using System;
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Net; 
using System.Net.Sockets; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Threading; 
using UnityEngine;  

public class TCPServer : MonoBehaviour {    
    #region private members     
    /// <summary>   
    /// TCPListener to listen for incomming TCP connection  
    /// requests.   
    /// </summary>  
    private TcpListener tcpListener; 
    /// <summary> 
    /// Background thread for TcpServer workload.   
    /// </summary>  
    private Thread tcpListenerThread;   
    /// <summary>   
    /// Create handle to connected tcp client.  
    /// </summary>  
    private TcpClient connectedTcpClient;   
    #endregion  

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {         
        // Start TcpServer background thread        
        tcpListenerThread = new Thread (new ThreadStart(ListenForIncommingRequests));       
        tcpListenerThread.IsBackground = true;      
        tcpListenerThread.Start();  
    }       

    /// <summary>   
    /// Runs in background TcpServerThread; Handles incomming TcpClient requests    
    /// </summary>  
    private void ListenForIncommingRequests () {        
        try {           
            // Create listener on localhost port 8052.          
            tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8052);             
            tcpListener.Start();              
            Debug.Log("Server is listening");              
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];              
            while (true) {              
                using (connectedTcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient()) {                    
                    // Get a stream object for reading                  
                    using (NetworkStream stream = connectedTcpClient.GetStream()) {                         
                        int length;                         
                        // Read incomming stream into byte arrary.                      
                        while ((length = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0) {                           
                            var incommingData = new byte[length];                           
                            Array.Copy(bytes, 0, incommingData, 0, length);                             
                            // Convert byte array to string message.                            
                            string clientMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(incommingData);                             
                            Debug.Log("client message received as: " + clientMessage);                      
                        }                   
                    }               
                }           
            }       
        }       
        catch (SocketException socketException) {           
            Debug.Log("SocketException " + socketException.ToString());         
        }     
    }   
    /// <summary>   
    /// Send message to client using socket connection.     
    /// </summary>  
    public void SendData(string message) {      
        if (connectedTcpClient == null) {             
            return;         
        }       

        try {           
            // Get a stream object for writing.             
            NetworkStream stream = connectedTcpClient.GetStream();          
            if (stream.CanWrite) {                      
                // Convert string message to byte array.                 
                byte[] serverMessageAsByteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);                 
                // Write byte array to socketConnection stream.               
                stream.Write(serverMessageAsByteArray, 0, serverMessageAsByteArray.Length);    
                stream.Flush();
                Debug.Log("Server sent his message - should be received by client");           
            }       
        }       
        catch (SocketException socketException) {             
            Debug.Log("Socket exception: " + socketException);         
        }   
    } 
}
```

I faced with the next issue. I send message in `Update` of my object to sync position on client. I do it in simple way, just put `x` and `z` coordinate into string with `;` separator. After receiving message I split it and take coordinates. But on client I can receive next message `0;00;00;00;00;00;00;00;00;00;00;00;00;00;0`. Messages just sticks together and it is impossible to parse it. Can somebody help me? How I can (if it is possible) split messages, send and receive it one by one?
Thanks.

Comment: Put a terminating character at end (like a '\n') and then wait until you get the terminating character.  TCP has maximum datagrams around 1500 bytes and can be split by routers and windows processing.  So to split you either have to specify where the message ends or read one character at a time.

Comment: When using TCP, you can't just fill the buffer and then read everything from it, you need to send a msg that contains a "header" that let's the user know how big the msg is, so it can be read accordingly.